# Existence of $(I-A)^{-1}$ implies convergence of $\sum A^k$?

Tags: matrices

Suppose $A$ is a square matrix (over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, take your pick) such that $(I-A)^{-1}$ exists. Then is it necessarily true that

$$I + A + A^2 + \dots + A^n + \dots = (I-A)^{-1}$$
?

There is a well known theorem which claims that if $||A|| \lt 1$ then $(I-A)^{-1}$ exists and the above is true.

What I am asking is something like the converse of that theorem. My hunch is that this is false, but I am unable to come up with a counter-example.

Comment: @Jonas Thanks for the link! And looking at the answer, I feel stupid now... :-)

Comment: $\sum A^k$ is convergent if $||A||<1$. This can be achieved using Jordan normal form. Thus the convergence of $\sum A^k$ is its corresponding function.

Comment: I find this may be not helpful to your question. sorry to misunderstand your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

take $A=2I$ not working.........................

Answer (score 3):

Ask the question even for a $1\times 1$ matrix.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I will accept the other answer as it is slightly more general.